# I want to be able to use authorization based on user roles, but here is my issue:

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

When I use, services.AddDefaultIdentity, I am able to use the built-in login service of asp.net core (Individual User Account enabled in authorization), however, despite assigning an Admin role to a user,  I am constantly getting access denied.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
  .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

When I use, services.AddIdentity, I am not even able to log in.

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I basically want to be able to log in, and if the user is an admin, give the user access to a particular controller, but neither `Services.AddIdentity`, not `Services.AddDefaultIdentity` is allowing me to do that.

What approach should I take?

Comment: Can you give out more information? Like how you seed users and roles initially? How you configure the `IdentityDbContext`? Screenshot of the migration folder? Your `AccountController`, etc?

Comment: When I created the Asp.Net Core MVC app, I chose Individual User Account as authentication. I did not configure IdentityDbContext, my ApplicationDbContext however inherits from IdentityDbContext. 

I initially login through twitter with an account, the user is then registered in AspNetUsers. 

From there I followed [this tutorial](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51333.asp-net-core-2-0-getting-started-with-identity-and-role-management.aspx) to add admin role and to assign it to the user created. 

I do not have an AccountController.

Comment: @57913 Can you please check your database either this role has been created or not. If it's created then does AspNetUserRole table has this role id with your user id.

Comment: @ZubairRana Yes I checked, both AspNetUserRoles and AspNetRoles have been populated with the correct values.

Comment: then please share your code instead of giving a link of someone else code.

Comment: @ZubairRana I opened the code this morning and tried it, it just started working ^^'